# Change specific character color in whole of the text

Tags: html, css

There is a problem with a text which I want to change the colour of some characters like all of the stars.

My text is something like this:

```
<p> Pedram Marandi * is a developer * He works at Foolanja. </p>
```

I want to change the colour of * to red.

I've tried this code:

```
  p:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
 }
```

But it seems this code will add a star after my p tag. 
How can I do this ? is it possible with only CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with css only, but you can use javascript for that. For example:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"), function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\*/g, "<span class='color-red'>*</span>");
});
```

```css
.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Pedram Marandi * is a developer * He works at Foolanja.</p>
```

Comment: As I've observed, I think so, it's not possible with CSS. By the way, thank you, I did what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by adding a specific tag for the star with a specific CSS Class.

HTML:

```
<p> Pedram Marandi <i class="star">*</i> is a developer <i class="star">*</i> He works at Foolanja. </p>
```

CSS:

```
.star {color:red;}
```

Comment: I'm not able to do it because my source code is based on react and this line is in a property. I'm not able to write html codes

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible in CSS.

Comment: You can do it by JQuery. Replace all stars to a formatted html .